# Is there any way to remove the title band from csv export in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I was trying to export my jasper report to csv format where I had removed the repetitive headers and footers but I also want to remove the report title band which should give me the clean data. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution myself,

You just need to add an property in your report source as below,

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.title" value="title"/>
```

As being newbie it will be difficult to find the solution, and i don't understand why people are down voting instead trying to answer it.

Comment: I gave you an upvote as I'm looking for a similar answer. I can't say why your question was downvoted, but I know questions get more traction if there is some kind of code example for what you tried.